# Only show last four labels on bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

My code here produces a bar graph with labels on each bar of the y value.
I would like to only show the last 4 data points as the labels. What is the best way to do it?
[image]

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.table(x= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), y=c(4,1,-3,-5,4,1,2,4,2,-3))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        geom_text(aes(y=y, ymax=y, label=y), 
                  position= position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-.5, color="red")
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you change the `geom_text` to `geom_text(data=subset(df, x>6),aes(y=y, ymax=y, label=y), 
                  position= position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-.5, color="red")`

Comment: Follow up question, is it possible to change the color for only the last 4 bars as well? Thank you.

Comment: You can change the first line to `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x>6)) +` . For more control over the colours, you can use `scale_fill_manual`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user20650 for the quick response. Subsetting the gem_text did the trick. Thank you very much!

Here is the updated code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.table(x= c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8,9,10), y=c(4, 1,-3,-5,4,1,2,4,2,-3))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity") +
        geom_text(data=subset(df, x>6), aes(y=y, ymax=y, label=y), 
                  position= position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-.5, color="red")
```

[image]